# How to check the endIndex of a String via IF?

Tags: swift

I want the calculator i am making, specifically the backspace button to check if the dot is erased

```
if mainNumberLine.text!.endIndex == "." {

}
```

writing that I get the most common error for me "Expression type is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: If you need to check this every time a key is pressed then I think you need to implement the delegate method `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use indices here. You can rewrite your condition in following manner:

```
if let text = mainNumberLine.text,
     text.last == "." {

}
```

Comment: Get the `.text!.` property

Comment: @ `mainNumberLine` is an instance of `UITextField`. It doesn't have a property as `last`. You should get the last character of the text field text using `mainNumberLine.text!.last`

Comment: Yes, you're right, thought of string instance with older API for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

To check if `"."` is erased with `backspace`, you just need to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.isEmpty && textField.text?.last == "." {
        print(". is erased")
    }
    return true
}
```

In the above code,

1. `string.isEmpty` identifies if the `replacementString` is an `empty string`, i.e. `backspace` is pressed.
2. `textField.text?.last` identifies if the last `character` of `textField` is a `"."`